# Why won't my image show up in email signature?

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, signature

I've been making a pretty simple email signature for a client and for the life of me can't work out why the end bloody image won't show up. I've checked it's there dozens of times. It's within the site's /images/ folder and ready to go. But it won't show up!

I've made a html file to go into Outlook signature bit. The img src is http://transitions-london.co.uk/images/Transsignature.jpg/. But it just won't show up. So infuriating! Any ideas will be joyful at this point. Thanks!

```
    <html>
<head> </head>
<body>

<table border="0" style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:30px;width:95%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="400">
<h2>Sheila Heard</h2>
<h3>Managing Director</br>
 <a href=“http://transitions-london.co.uk”>Transitions London CIC</a>     </br>
```

tel 020 86424431/07866 25742
     **Social Enterprise C.I.C. no 7609324**

```
 <i>Quality, impartial careers guidance and jobsearch services. Also social enterprise pathways for corporates to support and hire experienced professionals with refugee backgrounds & to deliver on corporate diversity and CSR good practice.</i>

  <i>Candidates are mostly engineers, finance & administration and international development professionals. Refugees have full permission to work.  Contact us for responsible services.</i>
```

Find us on [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=93188047&authType=OUT_OF_NETWORK&authToken=v9BE&locale=en_US&srchid=801359921417104438707&srchindex=1&srchtotal=3&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A801359921417104438707%2CVSRPtargetId%3A93188047%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary), [Twitter (@TransitionsUK)](https://twitter.com/TransitionsUK) and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Transitions-London-CIC/183567548331595)

```
 <img src=“http://transitions-london.co.uk/images/Transsignature.jpg”>     </img>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>


     </body>
  </html>
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nonstandard quote in the image url.  Use this:

```
<img src="http://transitions-london.co.uk/images/Transsignature.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: I tried this before. But for some reason it wasn't working. Now I've added the 'alt=""' it seems to be working! Very strange. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The image is not available. Even I couldn't open it in the web browser.

Also try to use the single element:

```
 <img src=“http://transitions-london.co.uk/images/Transsignature.jpg”/>
```